# Force and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electric-current

what is the force on the piece of wire from the infinite conductor?? what is the force on the infinite conductor from the piece of wire??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(The question is written pretty poorly "current-carrying conductor flows from current I1"?, you could try improving its writting, but I'll try writing a general concept for the answer)

Yes, as **Newton 3rd law** says.

Just think that a magnetic field only exerts force over other charges with velocity $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$, and charges moving produce magnetic fields, so **a magnetic field only exerts force over other things with a magnetic field of their own**.

And then as you can imagine, one magnetic field makes force over one wire, while the magnetic field of this wire also exerts a force over the original!

---

---

**Answer to the edited question:**
The infinite conductor does a magnetic field proportional to 1/r which is perpendicular to the wire current, so you would need to integrate the differential of forces as:
\begin{equation}
dF(x) =dq vB(x)= \rho dx v B(x)= J B(x) dx
\end{equation} where $(dq= \rho dx$ and $J=\rho v)$, which then gives:
\begin{equation}
F_{total} =\int \frac{aJ}{x} dx \ \text{ from the start of the wire to the end}
\end{equation} where $B=a/x$ (check yourself what a is), finally giving:

\begin{equation}
F_{total} =aJ \ ln(x/x_0) \ \text{ from the start of the wire($x_0$) to the end ($x$).}
\end{equation}
from the start of the wire to the end.

Comment: what is the direction of the force exerted by the wire on the conductor flowing through the current I1? 
does the magnetic field created by the wire affect conductor I1? (conductor and wire are not parallel)

Comment: You should write better and with more effort the questions if you really want people to answer you... edit the original question and make it clearer and I'll answer right away.

Comment: i write more simple

Comment: I edited the answer, gl

Comment: Your answer is for the first question. It's ok thanks. What is the force on the infinite conductor from the piece of wire?? Is the same? And what are the directions?

Comment: The total amount is the same but each contribution is not, you would need to do a double integration, first from the source and then of the part that recieves the force. The directions are easily computed with the right hand rule if you consider thatba current are electrons moving (charges moving), and F=q v x B